# How can I prove this grammar is ambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

S → ASB | ab | SS
A → aA  | ε
B → bB  | ε

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a “do my homework (for free)” site.

Comment: `S->SS` is always ambiguous (unless there is no other production for `S`, in which case it is useless). It's worth figuring out why that's true.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the word "ab" by two ways:
S -> ab
or
S -> SS -> aAS -> aS -> abB -> ab

This is why your grammar is ambigous :)